# How to put a 2 sec counter in a for loop

Tags: verilog

I want to have a 2 sec counter in my for loop such that there is a gap of 2 seconds between every iteration.I am trying to have a shifting LEDR Display

Code:

```
 parameter n =10;
 integer i;

 always@(*)
 begin
    for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1)
    begin
       LEDR[i]=1'b1;
       //2 second counter here
    end

 end
```

Comment: Can you clarify? There's only one assignment in that code.

Comment: I would suggest using embedded solution (microcontroller) instead of ASIC/FPGA but if u still want to use Verilog/FPGA solution then u may need to proceed as @Josh has specified OR use some FPGA and a C library to implement flashing/sliding LED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this module implements what Josh was describing. This module will create two registers, a counter register (counter_reg) and a shift register (leds_reg). The counter register will increment once per clock cycle until it rolls over. When it rolls over, the "tick" variable will be equal to 1. When this happens, the shift register will rotate by one position to the left.

```
module led_rotate_2s (
    input wire clk,
    output wire [N-1:0] leds,
);

parameter N=10;                 // depends on how many LEDs are on your board
parameter WIDTH=<some integer>; // depends on your clock frequency
localparam TOP=<some integer>;  // depends on your clock frequency

reg [WIDTH-1:0] counter_reg = 0, counter_next;
reg [N-1:0] leds_reg = {{N-1{1'b0}}, 1'b1}, leds_next;

wire tick = (counter_reg == 0);

assign leds = leds_reg;

always @* begin : combinational_logic
    counter_next = counter_reg + 1'b1;
    if (counter_next >= TOP)
        counter_next = 0;
    leds_next = leds_reg;
    if (tick)
        leds_next = {leds_reg[N-2:0], leds_reg[N-1]}; // shift register
end

always @(posedge clk) begin : sequential_logic
    counter_reg <= counter_next;
    leds_reg <= leds_next;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 4):

What is your desired functionality? I assume: shifting which LED is on every 2 seconds, keeping all the other LEDs off? "Sliding LED"...

Also, I am assuming your target is an FPGA-type board.

There is no free "wait for X time" in the FPGA world. The key to what you are trying to do it counting clock cycles. You need to know the clock frequency of the clock that you are using for this block. Once you know that, then you can calculate how many clock rising edges you need to count before "an action" needs to be taken.

I recommend two processes. In one, you will watch rising edge of clock, and run a counter of sufficient size, such that it will roll over once every two seconds. Every time your counter is 0, then you set a "flag" for one clock cycle.

The other process will simply watch for the "flag" to occur. When the flag occurs, you shift which LED is turned on, and turn all other LEDs off.